# Como inicializar o postgresql com o ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Estou com o seguinte problema, toda vez que ligo a minha máquina, vou até o terminal e dou `sudo service postgresql status`, aparece sempre `9.3/main (port 5432): down`.

Em outras máquinas que tenho instalado, ele inicia junto com o ubuntu, e quando rodo o mesmo comando aparece `9.3/main (port 5432): online`, não fiz nada de diferente, mas parece que em minha máquina está faltando alguma configuração.

Toda vez que vou utilizar o banco de dados pela primeira vez, é preciso dar um start no serviço.

No momento da instalação, foi exibida a seguinte mensagem, não sei se tem algo a ver com o erro: `No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"`

Estou utilizando o Ubuntu 14.04 e o Postgresql 9.3

Arquivo **postgresql.conf**:

```
# - Connection Settings -

#listen_addresses = 'localhost'     # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                # comma-separated list of addresses;
                # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
# Note:  Increasing max_connections costs ~400 bytes of shared memory per
# connection slot, plus lock space (see max_locks_per_transaction).
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
                # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                # (change requires restart)
```

Ao instalar o Postgres aparece a seguinte informação:

```
Removing obsolete dictionary files:
 * No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Configurando postgresql-9.3 (9.3.4-1) ...
Creating new cluster 9.3/main ...
 config /etc/postgresql/9.3/main
 data   /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
 locale pt_BR.UTF-8
 port   5432
update-alternatives: a usar /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz para disponibilizar /usr/share/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz (postmaster.1.gz) em modo automático
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
```

Obrigado.

Answer (score 9):

Se em algum momento da sua instalação você viu uma mensagem semelhante a:

```
warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = (unset),
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LC_TIME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
 LC_MONETARY = "de_DE.UTF-8",
 LC_ADDRESS = "de_DE.UTF-8",
 LC_TELEPHONE = "de_DE.UTF-8",
 LC_NAME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
 LC_MEASUREMENT = "de_DE.UTF-8",
 LC_IDENTIFICATION = "de_DE.UTF-8",
 LC_NUMERIC = "de_DE.UTF-8",
 LC_PAPER = "de_DE.UTF-8",
 LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
```

Isso significa que o PostgreSQL não conseguiu criar o cluster por causa do erro acima. Para corrigir o problema:

1) Reconfigure seus locales:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

2) Crie o cluster corretamente (minha versão é a 9.3):

```
# pg_createcluster 9.3 main --start
```

3) Inicie o PostgreSQL:

```
# /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

Answer (score 6):

Você provavelmente não colocou o `postgresql` para iniciar no *boot*. 
No terminal execute o comando:

```
sudo update-rc.d postgresql defaults
```

Para mais informações veja [`update-rc.d(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/update-rc.d.8.html).

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela resposta, porém, não funcionou, quando eu executei o comando, apareceu a seguinte mensagem `System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/postgresql already exist.` E ao reiniar o computador, continuou o serviço como down.

Comment: @AndersonPierok você utiliza algum firewall? tente também postar o arquivo de config do seu postgre com o IP que ele foi atribuido e porta.

Comment: @AndersonPierok Faça também `sudo update-rc.d postgresql enable`.

Comment: Não funciono @Sunstreaker, onde eu encontro esse arquivo @OlimonF.? Firewall não é, pq ele foi recém formatado ao mesmo instante que um outro, e o outro funcionou normalmente o start do banco de dados no boot, só esse que não quer funcionar.

Comment: @AndersonPierok Tente então, no terminal, `insserv postgresql` como root.

Comment: @AndersonPierok pelo que vi o arquivo de config (em distros debian) fica em __/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf__ mas o 9.4 deve ser substituido pela sua versão atual

Comment: @Sunstreaker `sudo: insserv: command not found`... @OlimonF. está na pergunta as configurações que você solicitou.
Obrigado aos dois pelo empenho.

Answer (score 4):

Seguindo a resposta aceita e algumas informações que vi no stackexchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50906/why-wont-postgresql-9-3-start-on-ubuntu (se ainda nao resolver tente ler esse)

## Ter certeza de que o socket possa ser criado

Temos que fazer com que o socket possa ser criado, então tenha certeza de que o diretório **/var/run/postgresql** exista e tenhas as permissões corretas (de ler e escrever)

### Vamos fazer um teste com TCP/IP

mude o seu postgresql.conf para rodar no IP 127.0.0.1 para vermos o que acontece, pode haver um bug com sockets talvez ou algo do tipo, apesar de ser um chute você pode tentar.

## Iniciando corretamente

Segundo o tópico original *(bug?)* Para iniciar o postgre você irá precisar da chave -h, que especifica uma host. Desse jeito:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1
```

## Se ainda não funcionar

Se nada funcionar, você tem 2 opções, por ordem de recomendação, 1 melhor e a 2 pior:

#### 1- apt-get com alguns hacks..

Já que o Ubuntu possui seu próprio sistema de pacotes, você pode reinstalar totalmente o postgre pelo apt-get e mais alguns hacks aque achei em russo(?) http://it-admin.org/os-linux/warn-no-postgresql-clusters-exist-see-man-pg_createcluster-warning.html

```
sudo apt-get purge postgresql postgresql-contrib   # Remover configurações e o pacote

rm -r /etc/postgresql/
rm -r /etc/postgresql-common/
rm -r /var/lib/postgresql/
userdel -r postgres
groupdel postgres

sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib # Reinstalar tudo
```

Agora que já reinstalamos, se ainda dar uma mensagem de erro com clusters:

```
pg_lsclusters
pg_createcluster 9.3 main --start
```

se ainda sim não iniciar, cheque o seu script em /etc/init.d/(postgresql?)
e adicione isso:

```
#-- EDITADO --#
#POSTGRE FIX#
# create socket directory
if [ -d /var/run/postgresql ]; then
  chmod 2775 /var/run/postgresql
else
  install -d -m 2775 -o postgres -g postgres /var/run/postgresql
  [ -x /sbin/restorecon ] && restorecon -R /var/run/postgresql || true
fi
#--/EDITADO--#
```

#### 2- Formatar ou desistir de sua vida

Esse é a menos aconselhada, mas se funcionou nas outras máquinas, você poderia formatar para ver o que acontece... Ou fazer um monte de gambiarra com o risco de ferrar o sistema.

## Notas

Talvez você queira dar uma lida nesse arquivo da documentação para ajudar a configurar: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-connection.html

E essa questão que também é do SO pode ajudar: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50906/why-wont-postgresql-9-3-start-on-ubuntu

foi tudo que achei, se nada funcionar é melhor você reinstalar o Ubuntu ou criar outra partição para um outra instalação, ou ainda rodar na VM...

Qualquer coisa comenta na resposta

Comment: Desinstalei e instalei o Postgres e nada adiantou, acrescentei na pergunta as informações obtidas ao instalar o Postgres novamente. Será que pode ser alguma coisa relacionada a mensagem "* No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see `'man pg_createcluster'`"

Comment: @AndersonPierok atualizei a resposta com mais informações, tente reinstalar novamente do novo jeito. note que esqueci de alguns sudo, então execute como o root ou adicione os sudo, Precsio perguntar tambem: 
Você está tentando iniciar de que jeito o postgre? /etc/init.d?